# Why is Firefox for Android leaving a udp socket open?

Tags: android, sockets, firefox, udp, fennec

As soon as you open a web page, Fennec (Firefox for android) is opening a UDP socket on a random port. What is this socket and why is it needed?

```
cat /proc/net/udp                                             
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops             
  361: 00000000:ABC2 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 10074        0 61366 2 00000000 0  

netstat                                                   
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 udp       0      0 0.0.0.0:43970          0.0.0.0:*              CLOSE
```

The problem is that it never gets closed as long as Firefox is open and this is failing Google's CTS compliance.